# ember.js: stack overflow with a route

Tags: ember.js

I have this router:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @route "index", path: "/"
  @resource "raw_materials", ->
    @route 'new'    
    @resource "raw_material", {path: ":raw_material_id"}, ->
      @route 'edit'
```

I place myself at url: `raw_materials/20` and i click on my edit button (it links to `raw_materials/20/edit`) and ember gives me a stack overflow:

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
guidFor
iterDeps
dependentKeysDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
chainsDidChange
propertyDidChange
contentPropertyDidChange
sendEvent
Ember.notifyObservers
propertyDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.chainDidChange
ChainNodePrototype.didChange
```

Here are my routes:

```
App.RawMaterialsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> App.RawMaterial.find()controller.get('currentPage')})

App.RawMaterialRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    App.RawMaterial.find(params.raw_material_id)
```

and here my templates:

```
---------------------
application.hbl:
{{outlet}}
---------------------
raw_materials.hbl:
{{#each controller}}
  <tr>
    <td>
       {{#linkTo raw_material this}}
         {{name}}
       {{/linkTo}}
    </td>
    <td>
       {{quantity}}
    </td>
    <td>
      <button {{action destroy this target="controller"}} class='btn btn-danger btn-small'>
        <i class="icon-white icon-remove"></i>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
{{outlet}}
---------------------
raw_material.hbl
{{name}}
{{quantity}}

{{#linkTo raw_material.edit this class='btn btn-warning btn-small'}}
<i class="icon-white icon-edit"></i>
{{/linkTo}}
---------------------
raw_material/edit.hbl
edit form....
```

any ideas about this?
thank you very much

Comment: try {{#linkTo raw_material.edit model class='btn btn-warning btn-small'}}

Comment: no exceptions. it logs this: `Transitioned into 'raw_materials.raw_material.edit' `, but i can't see my content. I placed all the needed outlets, and my template under `raw_materials/raw_material/edit`

Comment: your template should be under `raw_material/edit.hbs` not `raw_materials/raw_material/edit.hbs`

Comment: you're right. Why that, if my logs say they are in 'raw_materials.raw_material.edit'` this route?

Comment: you are actually in `raw_materials.raw_material.edit`, but since `raw_material` is a resource, you don't specify what's before it for template names or route names.

Comment: good. Thank you, very clear

Comment: oh.. last thing. Why in the first comment you suggested to pass as actual parameter `model` and not `this` ? (when i debug those variables it's clear they are different (one is a model, the other is a controller), but, if they are, why i can use `{{id}}` in same way as `{{model.id}}` ?

Comment: Because the controller is a proxy since it's an `ObjectController`. more info here: http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-a-single-model-with-objectcontroller/

You can access attributes of the `model` property using `controller.<property>` instead of `controller.model.<property>`

BTW, I think with the newest Ember version you should be able to pass `this` to `{{linkTo}}`